# Failing to compile Tomcat's index.jsp example

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jaas, scriptlet

Whenever I try to run the `index.jsp` example provide by Tomcat on `/jsp/security/protected`, I get the following error:

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
28: <body bgcolor="white">
29: 
30: You are logged in as remote user
31: <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getRemoteUser()) %></b>
32: in session <b><%= session.getId() %></b><br><br>
33: 
34: <%


An error occurred at line: 38 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
35:   if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
36: %>
37:     Your user principal name is
38:     <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getUserPrincipal().getName()) %></b>
39:     <br><br>
40: <%
41:   } else {


An error occurred at line: 56 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
53:     if (request.isUserInRole(role)) {
54: %>
55:       You have been granted role
56:       <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %></b><br><br>
57: <%
58:     } else {
59: %>


An error occurred at line: 61 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
58:     } else {
59: %>
60:       You have <i>not</i> been granted role
61:       <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %></b><br><br>
62: <%
63:     }
64:   }


An error occurred at line: 70 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
67: To check whether your username has been granted a particular role,
68: enter it here:
69: <form method="GET" action='<%= response.encodeURL("index.jsp") %>'>
70: <input type="text" name="role" value="<%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %>">
71: </form>
72: <br><br>
73: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The code of the file is

```
<%
  if (request.getParameter("logoff") != null) {
    session.invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    return;
  }
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Protected Page for Examples</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

You are logged in as remote user
<b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getRemoteUser()) %></b>
in session <b><%= session.getId() %></b><br><br>

<%
  if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
%>
    Your user principal name is
    <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(request.getUserPrincipal().getName()) %></b>
    <br><br>
<%
  } else {
%>
    No user principal could be identified.<br><br>
<%
  }
%>

<%
  String role = request.getParameter("role");
  if (role == null)
    role = "";
  if (role.length() > 0) {
    if (request.isUserInRole(role)) {
%>
      You have been granted role
      <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %></b><br><br>
<%
    } else {
%>
      You have <i>not</i> been granted role
      <b><%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %></b><br><br>
<%
    }
  }
%>

To check whether your username has been granted a particular role,
enter it here:
<form method="GET" action='<%= response.encodeURL("index.jsp") %>'>
<input type="text" name="role" value="<%= util.HTMLFilter.filter(role) %>">
</form>
<br><br>

If you have configured this app for form-based authentication, you can log
off by clicking
<a href='<%= response.encodeURL("index.jsp?logoff=true") %>'>here</a>.
This should cause you to be returned to the logon page after the redirect
that is performed.

</body>
</html>
```

As I assume it's a well tested example, I guess I'm missing something, a library or something. What could be the problem?

The JAAS implementation is OK, because I can login if I point directly at the `login.jsp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the log, the JSP engine was not able to find the class `util.HTMLFilter`.

If it's a 3rd party then the jar file should be there in `WEB-INF/lib`, if it's the class that you write then the compiled *.class file should be there in `WEB-INF/classes` and the package name should be correct.

Comment: copied the whole WEB-INF content of the examples folder, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error message says

```
util.HTMLFilter cannot be resolved to a type
```

So you should check if you have a package `util`, a class `HTMLFilter` in that package and that all the dependencies that `HTMLFilter` has are met, e.g. all members of that class are on the classpath as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert it to the JSP page at the top

```
<%@ page import="util.HTMLFilter" %>
```

Without it JSP won't compile a class referenced in the underline code.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, all you need to do is copy the HTMLFilter.java source file from WEB-INF/classes/util/, and place it in your corresponding Eclipse src/util/HTMLFilter.java (creating directories as needed), right-click on project, Build Project, and you're good to go.

If you're not using Eclipse, then just copy the HTMLFilter.class from the same directory into your corresponding WEB-INF/classes/util/ directory.